# Haskell Converting or Dealing with Multiple Custom Data Types

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

I am new to Haskell and am attempting to filter specific Custom Data types. I have been going through the Programming in Haskell book by Graham Hutton but seem to just be confusing myself more and more.

So given the following type definitions:

```hs
data Suit= Hearts
    deriving Eq

data Rank= Numeric Int | Jack
    deriving Eq

data Card= NormalCard Rank Suit | Joker
    deriving Eq
```

I am trying to create a condition that filters out specific Cards, i.e

```hs
filterCondition:: Card -> Bool
filterCondition i = isJack && isJoker
    where 
        isAce = i == Jack -- error here: Couldn't match expected type ‘Card’ with actual type ‘Rank’
        isJoker = i == Joker
```

The issue is the following error

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Card’ with actual type ‘Rank’
```

I was wondering how to handle the conditions given that a 'Rank' should be considered a "Card"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deconstruct `i` in this case:

```
isAce = case i of
  NormalCard r s -> r == Jack
  _ -> False
```

Comment: Good to know, I will look more into deconstruction. Many thanks